# usage in this example

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

A survey **was** written by the company.  (sentence)  (past tense)

A survey written by a company (phrase). (no tense)

A survey written by a company suggested there were faults in the business.

Does this last example require (which was) written by a company. Is it just the writers choice. Isn't the meaning the same?

**It** was a survey written by a company.  (Is **it* the subject or survey) ?

Answer (score 1):

It is common in English to leave out the "which/that is/was/are" of a relative clause, even in formal writing.

> A survey which was written by a  company -> a survey written by a company.

This process is known to linguistics as [Whiz deletion](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650)